# Splitting a string in pandas and join it to the old data

Tags: python, pandas

What I am doing seems simple, but I can not figure it out.

I have dataframe with data such as

```
City    State ZIP
Ames    IA    50011-3617
Ankeny  IA    50021
```

I want to split the zipcodes by `-` and save only the first ones in a new dataframe which has the old data and only the new zipcode. I tried to do the following.

```
data_short_zip = data
df = data['ZIP'].str.split('-').str[0]
data_short_zip.join(df)
```

This not only throws an error, but seems unpythonic. Is there a simple way to do this?

The output data would look like

```
City    State ZIP
Ames    IA    50011
Ankeny  IA    50021
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to split on your delimeter and then `str[0]` on the result to return the first split:

```
In [122]:
df['ZIP'] = df['ZIP'].str.split('-').str[0]
df

Out[122]:
     City State    ZIP
0    Ames    IA  50011
1  Ankeny    IA  50021
```

Comment: I want the results to be in a new data frame because I still want the original dataframe with the full zip codes. The new one would contain the old data but with the new shorter zip codes.

Comment: You can just do `new_df = df.copy()` and then do the above `new_df['ZIP'] = new_df['ZIP'].str.split('-').str[0]`

Comment: Not really because of your requirement to create a new df, you **have** to make a deep copy using `copy` first, otherwise you either raise a warning about working on a copy not a view

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately, you want to scrape those first 5 characters and reassign to `data.ZIP`.  Here are some alternatives to scrape the first 5, all of which return the same thing.

```
0    50011
1    50021
Name: ZIP, dtype: object

data.ZIP.str.extract(r'^(\d{5})', expand=False)
data.ZIP.str[:5]
data.ZIP.str.split('-').str[0]
data.ZIP.str.split('-').str.get(0)
```

---

It's pretty clear to me ;-)
`data.ZIP.str[:5]` is the winner.

Then just assign back to `data.ZIP`

```
data.ZIP = data.ZIP.str[:5]
```

[image]

---

#### Timing

#### Over the small 2 row sample, this is how fast they are:

[image]

#### Over that 2 row sample concatted 10000 times (20 Thousand rows)

```
data = pd.concat([data for _ in range(10000)])
```

[image]

#### Another 100 times (2 Million rows)

```
data = pd.concat([data for _ in range(100)])
```

[image]